# Boost thread pool join tasks without closing the pool

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++20

I am using boost asio thread pool. I have multiple "stop" points in my program where I'd like for it to hang up and wait for all of the tasks to be fed into the pool before moving on.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int large_object = 10;
    auto f1 = [&large_object](int x) {
        std::cout << "this is a very large object that needs passed by ref " << large_object << std::endl;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds {3});
        std::cout << "DONE SLEEPING!" << std::endl;
    };

    int processor_count = 2;  // consider that this CPU has two processors

    // Launch the pool with n threads.
    boost::asio::thread_pool pool(processor_count);

    int x = 2;
    // Submit a function to the pool.
    boost::asio::post(pool, [x, f1]{f1(x);});

    pool.join();

    // The pool is now unavailable, but I dont want this
    // I want to wait on the tasks to finish, but keep the pool "open" to be used for submitting new jobs
    x = 8;
    boost::asio::post(pool, [x, f1]{f1(x);});

    pool.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with

```
main.cpp -std=c++20 -pthread
```

My issue here is that after I call pool `join`, the pool appears to close. The second `post` to the pool doesn't behave properly.

How can I `join` without `close`?

Thank you for your time.